# Eigen::SparseTriangularView

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I am trying to switch some code from Eigen 3.2.10 to 3.3. I am running into compile errors with this method declaration

```
/// \brief Returns template expression for the lower triangular part of A.
Eigen::SparseTriangularView < SystemMatrixType, Eigen::Lower >
    getLowerTriangular() const;
```

producing `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'`.

It looks like `SparseTriangularView` has been renamed or replaced. What should `SparseTriangularView` or this whole declaration be replaced by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `TriangularView < SystemMatrixType, Eigen::Lower >`. Triangular and Selfadjoint views of dense and sparse expressions have been unified in 3.3.